# IOS Rotation Notification does not work

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, nsnotifications, addobserver

I'm trying NSNotificationCenter with this code:

[image: snapshot]

but does not print anything, never enters in the rotate function, any ideas? thanks a lot

Comment: Why are you passing the app object there? just pass  nil. Also looks like you have a breakpoint there

Comment: Can you replace the image with actual code?

Comment: check in your device , may be orientation is locked

Comment: Leo Dabus  has reason I have to put nil !!! works now, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you confirm that you've enabled the appropriate orientations under App General settings?

[image]